# How do you recover you RDS master user username?

Tags: password, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

Resetting the RDS master user's password is simple enough, but how do you find your master users username?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [master user name](https://jonsimpson.co.uk/2011/lost-rds-master-user-login) can be recovered with the [`rds-describe-db-instances`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-instances.html) command.

If you are using aws cli-2, command shall become :

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region ap-south-1
```

Comment: The 2nd link is no longer working

Comment: Good news, the second link works now. But the first doesn't.

Comment: the attribute from that JSON object is `MasterUsername`

Answer (score 43):

The master username is now listed in the RDS Dashboard.

1. Select the "Instances" listing and expand the DB instance.
2. Press the looking glass tab on the left.
3. The master username is listed in the left column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer as it doesn't require the API.  I might add that label/field name in the GUI is not 'Master User' but simply 'Username', which (as of this writing) currently appears under the 'DB Name'.

Comment: In 2017 update, the master user name is now under RDS > Instances > Connect > Master username

Comment: As of right now, the master user name is under RDS > Instances > Configuration > Master username.

Comment: I cannot find rds instance tab in my aws console. Can anyone share the instance url?

Comment: In 2020, the master user name is now under RDS > Databases > Choose Desired Cluster or Database > Configuration > Master username

Answer (score 21):

It is 2019 now. It is 'Databases' on the sidebar, 'Configuration' on the navigation bar. And look for username.

[image: Sidebar]

[image: Navigation bar]

Comment: This is what worked, as of Nov 22, 2019

Comment: where can I get the password for the user?

Answer (score 10):

With the new updated RDS UI, the username is present in the Details section of the Instance Information screen.

1. From the List of your running Instances, click an instance name to see information about the instance.
2. See the "Details" section of the information screen.

[image: rds instance info screen]

scroll down in that screen to see the "Details" section.

[image: your connection information is shown here]

Comment: In amazon aurora, it's under the "Configuration" tab

Comment: I see  no instance tab on my aws console

Comment: For Amazon Aurora, it's in the "Configuration" tab of the cluster entry under "Availability". The label for it is "Master username".

Answer (score 7):

Here is the command that you can use to get the master username of your RDS:

```
aws --profile=prod rds describe-db-instances
    --region us-east-1
    --db-instance-identifier YOUR-RDS-IDENTIFIER-HERE
    --query 'DBInstances[*].MasterUsername'
```

Note: Replace the `prod` with your aws profile and `YOUR-RDS-IDENTIFIER-HERE` with your rds instance identifier

It will give you the master username like this:

```
[
    "root"
]
```

Hope that might help future reader.

Comment: the above methods using the UI (including looking at the snapshot) did not work for me but this did. I didn't provide the `--profile-prod` because I wasn't sure what profile I had and it still worked as expected.

Comment: All of the answers that use the console become out of date so quickly (it's why i'm here today).  The API will work for years.  Do it this way everybody.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to *directly* find the aws admin username in 2019 AWS, however, you can see it in a snapshot.  Just follow:

Main RDS console > Snapshots > A snapshot of your database > Details > Master username

Comment: Only this method works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Using AWS CLI to get all Instance names + the respective Master users:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances | grep -e \"DBInstanceId -e Master
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT grantee 
FROM  sys.dba_role_privs 
WHERE granted_role='RDS_MASTER_ROLE' 
AND admin_option ='NO';
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Select the database and click top-right on `modify`

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) is the description how to do it:
[image: Breadcrumb on RDS Databases]

The third field is the password.